# How to determine if $n = 53467$ is prime or not using Elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, prime-factorization

I want to use Elliptic curves modulo $n$ to find out if $n$ is prime or not.

> Now, I know that $n = 53467 = 127\times 421$, but how do I find this out using Elliptic curves?

I tried factorization using Lenstra factorization, but how to choose an efficient Elliptic curve to get the factors fast?

Comment: If you only want to determine whether a number is prime, you should begin with a primality test. For proving the primality, you can use elliptic curves. Lenstra's method assumes that the given number is composite, so I don't think it will work, if the input is a prime number.

Comment: Noone knows how to choose "good" ECM-curves. It is just a matter of luck. But for very small numbers, you need usually only a few curves with low B1 to get a factor. But there is no guarantee if you do not find a factor that the input must be prime. ECM is probabilistic.

Comment: Elliptic curves can be used to prove Primality, but how to disprove primality, i.e. show that the number is a composite number?

Comment: I do not know a primality test based on elliptic curves. I would suggest Miller-Rabin instead. Or the powerful BPSW-test which has no known counterexample. For very small numbers, there are also deterministic Miller-Rabin variants.

Comment: @Shinimani, Could you give a numeric example for using elliptic curve to prove a number is prime? For example prove that  9907 is prime.

Comment: I am under the impression that elliptic curves modulo $n$ are used chiefly to find a non-trivial factor of $n$. Proving a number is a prime use AKS (or Miller-Rabin, if "industrial grade" is good enough for your purposes). Basically what @Peter said except that he is more familiar with this stuff than I am.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a computer search adapted to...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization

(There is not too much chance to provide an answer without letting the computer search for the answer.)

We pretend that $n=53467$ is a prime, and use a random elliptic curve of the shape $y^2 = x^3+ax$, a random point $P$ on it, and perform some operations with $P$...

```
n = 53467
R = Integers(n)
a = R.random_element()
E = EllipticCurve(R, [a, 0])
print(f'Using the random element a={a} in the ring (field?) R=ZZ/{n}')

for x0 in [1..n]:
    y0_2 = R(x0)^3 + a*R(x0)
    if y0_2.is_square():
        P = E.point( (R(x0), sqrt(y0_2)) )
    break

print(f'Using the random point P = {P.xy()} on\nE = {E}\n')

import traceback
for k in [1..n]:
    try:
        Q = k*P
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print(f'An error appeared for k={k}. Please analyze the reason above.')
        break
```

The above gave me this time...

```
Using the random element a=41275 in the ring (field?) R=ZZ/53467
Using the random point P = (1, 2097) on
E = Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 41275*x over Ring of integers modulo 53467
```

Then there is a final error message, showing something went wrong...

```
An error appeared for k=14. Please analyze the reason above.
```

And looking inside the looong traceback message, we explicitly can extract this reason:

```
    raise ZeroDivisionError(f"inverse of Mod({x}, {n}) does not exist")
ZeroDivisionError: inverse of Mod(13472, 53467) does not exist
```

We have an idea why this fails and ask for...

```
sage: gcd(13472, 53467)
421
```

Comment: Lenstra's method is usually only used if we already know that the given number is composite. Of course, we can use it to search for small factors , and if no factor was found, apply the primality test. But with Lenstra, we cannot prove primality, we need another algorithm based on elliptic curves for that. But basically, the author wants to decide whether a given number is prime.

Comment: @Peter This comment above is already longer than the question, which is explicitly " *I tried factorization using Lenstra factorization, but how to choose an efficient Elliptic curve to get the factors fast?* " It is not a detailed question, as i feel, it asks for some way to do something in the given situation. Anything. And i am doing something. (Since i got a downvote, this may be the reason, so i will detail. The comments to the question move the story in an other direction. The comments are also missing setting and context. The title of the OP is also an other question.) So the above...

Comment: @Peter ... answer is showing that starting with a random elliptic curve given by the affine equation $y^2=x^3+ax$ (so $a$ is a random choice) over the given toy ring $R=\Bbb Z/53467$, and a (more or less) random point $P$ (that i had to construct, sage does not provide it, since sage already knows $R$ is not a field, this makes the code longer...), then computing $kP$ for $k=1,2,3,...$ very, very often leads to a division by zero. So the answer is roughly "take any $a$, it will work..." and the answer comes with testing code. Note this is a naive toy adaptation of the Lenstra receipt.

Answer (score 0):

pari/gp code:

```
ecm()=
{
 n= 53467;
 a= random(n)+1;
 E= ellinit([a, 0], n);
 for(x=1, n,
  X= Mod(x,n);
  if(issquare(X^3+a*X),
   for(y=1, n,
    Y= Mod(y,n);
    if(X^3+a*X==Y^2,
     P= [x,y];
     break(2)
    )
   )
  )
 );
 for(k=1, n,
  iferr(
   ellmul(E, P, k), Err,
   print("E = ["a", "0"] by modulo "n);
   print("P = "P);
   print("k = "k);
   print("inverse error k*P: "Err);
   print("factor of "n" is "gcd(lift(component(Err, 2)), n)"\n");
   return()
  )
 )
};
```

Examples output:

```
? \r ecm.gp
? ecm()
E = [41853, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [1, 1440]
k = 14
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(421, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 421

? ecm()
E = [6631, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [6, 1817]
k = 28
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(421, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 421

? ecm()
E = [1381, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [6, 19259]
k = 64
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(127, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 127

? ecm()
E = [15203, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [6, 4434]
k = 30
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(421, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 421

? ecm()
E = [12638, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [5, 12587]
k = 32
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(127, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 127

? ecm()
E = [17202, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [6, 24050]
k = 30
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(421, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 421

? ecm()
E = [34955, 0] by modulo 53467
P = [3, 864]
k = 7
inverse error k*P: error("impossible inverse in Fp_inv: Mod(421, 53467).")
factor of 53467 is 421
```